# Splitting a data frame into a list of data frames by row number

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with a variable number or rows and would like to split it into a list of data frames (or just multiple dfs) by groups of nearby rows. Nearby rows that should be grouped together can be appreciated by the variable column w/ each group consisting of samples that are numerically next to each other. For example: rows 1-9 are one group, rows 10-12 are group 2, etc. The exact identities of what is in the variable column will not be consistent b/w datasets.

Here is the df:

```
> conseq_high
   variable 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 position rnum
1    pep_14 L L L L  Q  L  S  C  S        3    1
2    pep_15 L L L Q  L  S  C  S  Y        4    2
3    pep_16 L L Q L  S  C  S  Y  A        5    3
4    pep_17 L Q L S  C  S  Y  A  G        6    4
5    pep_18 Q L S C  S  Y  A  G  Q        7    5
6    pep_19 L S C S  Y  A  G  Q  F        8    6
7    pep_20 S C S Y  A  G  Q  F  R        9    7
8    pep_21 C S Y A  G  Q  F  R  V       10    8
9    pep_22 S Y A G  Q  F  R  V  I       11    9
10  pep_136 E L K V  E  D  P  F  Y       19   10
11  pep_137 L K V E  D  P  F  Y  W       20   11
12  pep_138 K V E D  P  F  Y  W  V       21   12
13  pep_164 V S V G  L  V  F  L  F       26   13
14  pep_165 S V G L  V  F  L  F  L       27   14
15  pep_166 V G L V  F  L  F  L  Q       28   15
16  pep_175 H R L R  G  K  L  R  A       30   16
17  pep_176 R L R G  K  L  R  A  E       31   17
18  pep_223 Y N W L  H  R  R  L  A       36   18
19  pep_224 N W L H  R  R  L  A  G       37   19
```

I have tried getting the positions of the last row in each group of rows that must be grouped together by:

```
#subset out individual groups of peptides
as_vector(conseq_high$position) -> seq2
xy1 <- c(diff(seq2),0)  
which(xy1 !=1) -> grp_ids #these are the ending positions of each group of peptides

>  grp_ids
[1]  9 12 15 17 19
```

From here I am having issues actually subsetting out the groups of rows I want. I have tried using split and splice w/ no success. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a grouping index with `cumsum` on a logical vector created based on the `diff`erence of adjacent elements in 'position' are not sequential i.e. the difference is not equal to 1

```
lst1 <-  split(conseq_high, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(conseq_high$position) != 1)))
```

-output

```
lst1
#$`1`
#  variable X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 position rnum
#1   pep_14  L  L  L  L   Q   L   S   C   S        3    1
#2   pep_15  L  L  L  Q   L   S   C   S   Y        4    2
#3   pep_16  L  L  Q  L   S   C   S   Y   A        5    3
#4   pep_17  L  Q  L  S   C   S   Y   A   G        6    4
#5   pep_18  Q  L  S  C   S   Y   A   G   Q        7    5
#6   pep_19  L  S  C  S   Y   A   G   Q   F        8    6
#7   pep_20  S  C  S  Y   A   G   Q   F   R        9    7
#8   pep_21  C  S  Y  A   G   Q   F   R   V       10    8
#9   pep_22  S  Y  A  G   Q   F   R   V   I       11    9

#$`2`
#   variable X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 position rnum
#10  pep_136  E  L  K  V   E   D   P   F   Y       19   10
#11  pep_137  L  K  V  E   D   P   F   Y   W       20   11
#12  pep_138  K  V  E  D   P   F   Y   W   V       21   12

#$`3`
#   variable X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 position rnum
#13  pep_164  V  S  V  G   L   V   F   L   F       26   13
#14  pep_165  S  V  G  L   V   F   L   F   L       27   14
#15  pep_166  V  G  L  V   F   L   F   L   Q       28   15

#$`4`
#   variable X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 position rnum
#16  pep_175  H  R  L  R   G   K   L   R   A       30   16
#17  pep_176  R  L  R  G   K   L   R   A   E       31   17
#$`5`
#   variable X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 position rnum
#18  pep_223  Y  N  W  L   H   R   R   L   A       36   18
#19  pep_224  N  W  L  H   R   R   L   A   G       37   19
```

#### data

```
conseq_high <- structure(list(variable = c("pep_14", "pep_15", 
   "pep_16", "pep_17", 
"pep_18", "pep_19", "pep_20", "pep_21", "pep_22", "pep_136", 
"pep_137", "pep_138", "pep_164", "pep_165", "pep_166", "pep_175", 
"pep_176", "pep_223", "pep_224"), X6 = c("L", "L", "L", "L", 
"Q", "L", "S", "C", "S", "E", "L", "K", "V", "S", "V", "H", "R", 
"Y", "N"), X7 = c("L", "L", "L", "Q", "L", "S", "C", "S", "Y", 
"L", "K", "V", "S", "V", "G", "R", "L", "N", "W"), X8 = c("L", 
"L", "Q", "L", "S", "C", "S", "Y", "A", "K", "V", "E", "V", "G", 
"L", "L", "R", "W", "L"), X9 = c("L", "Q", "L", "S", "C", "S", 
"Y", "A", "G", "V", "E", "D", "G", "L", "V", "R", "G", "L", "H"
), X10 = c("Q", "L", "S", "C", "S", "Y", "A", "G", "Q", "E", 
"D", "P", "L", "V", "F", "G", "K", "H", "R"), X11 = c("L", "S", 
"C", "S", "Y", "A", "G", "Q", "F", "D", "P", "F", "V", "F", "L", 
"K", "L", "R", "R"), X12 = c("S", "C", "S", "Y", "A", "G", "Q", 
"F", "R", "P", "F", "Y", "F", "L", "F", "L", "R", "R", "L"), 
    X13 = c("C", "S", "Y", "A", "G", "Q", "F", "R", "V", "F", 
    "Y", "W", "L", "F", "L", "R", "A", "L", "A"), X14 = c("S", 
    "Y", "A", "G", "Q", "F", "R", "V", "I", "Y", "W", "V", "F", 
    "L", "Q", "A", "E", "A", "G"), position = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 30L, 
    31L, 36L, 37L), rnum = 1:19), class = "data.frame", 
    row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19"))
```

Comment: Perfect solution and much cleaner than my approach. Thank you!